# mariadb won't create foreign key

Tags: foreign-keys, mariadb

I think I'm using the right syntax for MariaDB, but my foreign key constraint is not being created.

Here's the create table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  id INT auto_increment primary key,
  description TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE item_events (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  calendar_event_guid TEXT(255) NOT NULL,
  foreign key item_events_id_fk (id) REFERENCES items (id)
);
```

Then, when I ask MariaDB to show me what I created, I get this:

```
+-------------+-----------------
| Table       | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                       +-------------+-----------------
| item_events | CREATE TABLE `item_events` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `calendar_event_guid` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  KEY `item_events_id_fk` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
+-------------+-----------------
```

or, just showing the DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `item_events` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `calendar_event_guid` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  KEY `item_events_id_fk` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Notice that it only created a "KEY", not a foreign key. The items table is correctly created.

Surely, this is really simple  :)

Comment: myisam doesn't support fks. when debugging cut down your code until the error goes away. read the manual re all functionality you are using. this is a SO faq, it will be among the answers for the error message on some very old very upvoted question.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the problem. I discovered that my hosting company sets the default to myisam (and I can't change it). So, apparently, I need to specify InnoDB. As for "reading the manual" it's hard to know what things are relevant to read. I discovered this after making the post, but not until spending an hour or two reading and experimenting. Please post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it "correct".

Comment: duplicates should be closed not answered. i just googled 'mariadb only created a "KEY", not a foreign key myisam site:stackoverflow.com' & my first hit was re why myisam doesn't support fks. I'm not saying that this is an easily found duplicate amid the fk errors without 'myisam'. but ... changing 'myisam' to '-error', that post becomes my 7th hit. before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers.

Comment: It was a bit difficult. MarieDB didn't report any error at all. It simply, transparently, didn't create the FK. With an error message, it would have been much easier.

Comment: you can vote to close this as a duplicate yourself.

Comment: ok, will do. But thanks for your support. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Actually, I'm going to leave it. This is not a duplicate. Had there been an error message, then yes. But without an error message, this is a new case and one has to search quite exhaustively to discover the problem is due to MyIsam or know (as you did) apriori.

Comment: i just told you an answer is found googling (cutting & pasting your own phrase) 'mariadb only created a "KEY", not a foreign key -error site:stackoverflow.com'. this is not the first time someone has had this problem & asked about it. i'm done.

Comment: Technically, this is a duplicate. But it's important for this question to stay visible and searchable since the duplicate cases are pretty obscure to find.